# mocha unit test not working within callback

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to define my mocha tests in json and then parse them and run my tests. However, I find that I am having difficulty running the tests in the callback functions

```
function addTwoNumbers(a,b){
    return a+b;
}

function testAddNumbers(){
    describe("testing the addition of 2 numbers",() => {
        it('should return the addition',(done) => {
            addTwoNumbers(2,2).should.be.equal(4)
            done()
        })
    })
}

//Obtain all the test jsons
glob(__dirname +'/../**/*.doc.json', {} , (err,fileNames) => {
    fileNames.forEach(fileName => {
        let file = fs.readFileSync(fileName)
        let tests = JSON.parse(file)
        tests.forEach(test => {
            testAddNumbers()
        })
    })
})
```

Which returns:

```
Backend listening on port 3000


  0 passing (1ms)
```

Moving testAddNumbers() outside the glob block works, so I am not too sure of the problem. Eg:

```
function addTwoNumbers(a,b){
    return a+b;
}

function testAddNumbers(){
    describe("testing the addition of 2 numbers",() => {
        it('should return the addition',(done) => {
            addTwoNumbers(2,2).should.be.equal(4)
            done()
        })
    })
}

//Obtain all the test jsons
glob(__dirname +'/../**/*.doc.json', {} , (err,fileNames) => {
    fileNames.forEach(fileName => {
        let file = fs.readFileSync(fileName)
        let tests = JSON.parse(file)
        tests.forEach(test => {
            
        })
    })
})

testAddNumbers()
```

returns

```
Backend listening on port 3000


  testing the addition of 2 numbers
    √ should return the addition


  1 passing (238ms)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it in a way that I find rather disgraceful, but if you can do better do enlighten me

Problem:
Mocha was exiting when it reached the end of the file

Solution:
Loop and wait till file has completed running. This must be done within a mocha test or mocha will blatantly ignore you as if you were its mom

```
describe('Wait for dynamically added tests to complete', function () {
    this.timeout(999999999)
    it('Waiting...', function (done) {
        completed = (function wait() {
            // console.log(completed)
            // console.log('boomdiyadah')
            if (!completed) {
                setTimeout(wait, 1000)
            } else {
                done()
            }
        })();
    })

})
```

Probably this could be implemented with promises but my life needs to move forward